# GetElementById returning only last value from var

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

This is basically a soundboard that creates an `<audio>` for each track in database. I'm trying to create a volume bar for each `<audio>`, but all these volume bars are changing just the last one `<audio>`, I believe that there is something to do with GetElementById(), as it gets one ID per element.

```html
    <?php
            while($teste = $usr_idLogged_aTracks_r->fetch_assoc()) { 
                $trackId = $teste['atrack_id'];
                $trackTitle = $teste['atrack_title'];
                $trackPath = $teste['atrack_path'];
                $trackPlaylist = $teste['atrack_playlistId']; ?>

            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" >
              <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                  <h2><?php echo $trackTitle ?> <small> <?php echo $trackId ?> </small></h2>
                  <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                    <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fa fa-wrench"></i></a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Settings 1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Settings 2</a>
                        </li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="close-link"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">
                <div class="row">

                    <audio style=" width: 100%; max-width: 600px" id="<?php echo $trackId ?>" controls>
                        <source src="<?php echo $trackPath ?>" type="audio/mp3">
                    </audio>

                    <input id="vol-control" type="range" min="0" max="100" step="1" oninput="SetVolume(this.value)" onchange="SetVolume(this.value)"></input>

                    <button onclick="document.getElementById('<?php echo $trackId ?>').play()">Reproduzir o áudio</button>
                    <button onclick="document.getElementById('<?php echo $trackId ?>').pause()">Pausar o áudio</button>.

                    <script type="text/javascript">
                        window.SetVolume = function(val) {

                                var player = document.getElementById('<?php echo $trackId ?>');
                                console.log('Before: ' + player.volume);
                                player.volume = val / 100;
                                console.log('After: ' + player.volume);
                        }
                    </script>
                </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             </div>
            <?php }
            ?>
```

I have tried in many forms, but no success.

Comment: There can only be one function called "SetVolume" on the `window` object.

Comment: As @Pointy alluded to, the issue is not with getElementById; it's that you're re-defining window.SetVolume at every iteration of the loop. Each one overwrites the previous, so in the end, the function stored in the variable window.SetVolume is just the last one created, which points to the last track ID.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense. Is there a way to just use one function without redefinion inside this loop? Or, I don't know, create a for loop to deal with it?